# React-Native: Momentjs - is there a straightforward way how to throw all unused locales from production build

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webpack, momentjs, babeljs

I checked my app bundle with [react-native-bundle-visualizer](https://github.com/IjzerenHein/react-native-bundle-visualizer) and found out that locales of momentjs[image] weight almost 400kb. I'm using only English. I found solution for webpack with [ignore-plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/ignore-plugin/), but solution doesn't look lile RN one. So, if there is one for React-Native?